# Is it possible to reproduce this image using underbrace?

Tags: underbrace

I'm trying to recreate this image in latex and I came across underbrace but still I was not able to recreate it.

Is it doable?

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but I don't think it looks good.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) demonstrating what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

> Is it doable?

It's *doable*, but I wouldn't actually do it, as it's mind-bendingly ugly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
X_1
{\underbrace{{}=\$100{,}000 \qquad X_2=\$50}_{\text{50\% decrease}}}{,}
{\underbrace{000 \qquad X_3=\$100{,}}_{\text{100\% increase}}}000
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help